Cross-Origin Iframe Issue with Google One Tap despite Not Using Iframes
I'm facing an issue with my web application using Google One Tap for sign-in. Google notified me that there is a Cross-origin iframes issue detected, but I do not explicitly use iframes in my code.
Here is my current implementation:
<head>
  <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'nonce-1214' https://accounts.google.com; object-src 'none';">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="g_id_onload"
       data-client_id="---------"
       data-auto_select="false"
       data-cancel_on_tap_outside="false"
       data-context="signin"
       data-ux_mode="popup"
       data-state_cookie_domain=".kpopmap.com"
       data-callback="handleCredentialResponse"
       data-itp_support="true"
       data-use_fedcm_for_prompt="true">
  </div>

  <script nonce="1214">
    function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
        var id_token = response.credential; 
        console.log('id_token->' + id_token);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>

Despite not using iframes, Google One Tap seems to be detected as running within a cross-origin iframe. I suspect that third-party sites embedding my page might be causing this issue.
How can I resolve this? Is there a way to ensure the One Tap prompt works even when my page is embedded cross-origin?
Thank you!

data-use_fedcm_for_prompt="true" add
https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/fedcm-migration?hl=ko#cross_origin


People suggested some solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78586118/google-one-tap-cross-origin-iframes-issue-detected
