Google One-Tap and FedCM
A few months ago, we implemented Google One-Tap on our website.
The implementation is purly written in JavaScript and is working as expected. However, a few days ago, we received the following email from Google:

"We have identified one or more of your web applications that use the
One Tap - Sign In with Google for Web SDK and have not migrated to
Federated Credential Management (FedCM). 
What you need to know
Your app has not migrated for the following reason:
We temporarily disabled FedCM for your web applications as we detected
your current site configurations (cross-origin iframes and/or Content
Security Policy) may block the One Tap experience if FedCM is enabled.
Please take the necessary steps to verify and resolve any issues."

From Google's email, it seems we have a cross-origin iframe issue.
However, we don't use any iframes for Google One-Tap. Our implementation is purely JavaScript and does not involve any iframes.
Additionally, since we handle everything via JavaScript, we cannot manually add the allow="identity-credentials-get" attribute.
Any idea what could be the issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

People suggested some solutions here, hope it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78586118/google-one-tap-cross-origin-iframes-issue-detected

The best way to verify if your web app would work correctly when FedCM rollout is to enable FedCM now to test and verify it is working on your site. See Test and verify your migration. The email you received could be because some other sites embed your site, so it triggered the detection logic.
